# Trello API get old labels on a card

Tags: label, trello

Is there any way to get all the labels that were added and then removed from a card within a certain date range?.. I tried getting all the actions using the endpoint [/1/cards/[idCard]/actions](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#get-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-actions) but it doesn't seem to hold any log of the labels that were added and removed

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is at the moment.

You can pass **filter=all** in the URL to get all the actions on the card, which would include any label related ones if they exist. The default filter is **commentCard,updateCard:idList**

Comment: passing **filter=all** also doesn't seem to return any label related actions

Comment: That would suggest that there is no way to retrieve those actions then